# Anything that replicates this in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Is there anything that replicates this in wordpress? plugin 
or custom code [List of products](http://broadcast.bswusa.com/nav/type/products/cat1/broadcast/cat2/broadcast_rfequipment/cat3/broadcast_rfequipment_rdsencodersanddecoders/0)

Note: I am using WooCommerce

When I look at a category of products on my current site they are displayed as a grid I click the image and am taken to the product to buy etc. What I need is that when I view a category i get a list of products with an image, a description and add to cart link etc as shown in the link above

Comment: Replicates what? Too broad and will be closed unless you add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one ?
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-grid-list-toggle/

You can set the view to list/grid and set the default as list.